# Since updating to Ubuntu 14.04, Chromium causes black screen

Tags: drivers, graphics

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04. Since I did that, while surfing in Chromium, some sites cause my computer to go black. It's still on due to the power light, but I can't do anything and have to reboot.

I've read through several similar posts but no solution. One post said to look at about:gpu in chrome, below is what that pulled up -- I'm not very ubuntu savvy so I'm not sure what to do about all these problems detected -- any specific instructions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

---

Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash: Hardware accelerated
Flash Stage3D: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Compositing: Hardware accelerated and threaded
Rasterization: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Threaded Rasterization: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
Video Encode: Hardware accelerated
WebGL: Hardware accelerated

Driver Bug Workarounds
clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
count_all_in_varyings_packing
disable_ext_occlusion_query
disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces

Problems Detected
Accelerated 2d canvas is unstable in Linux at the moment
Disabled Features: accelerated_2d_canvas
Stage3D is not supported on Linux: 129848
Disabled Features: flash_stage3d
Accelerated video decode is unavailable on Mac and Linux: 137247, 133828
Disabled Features: accelerated_video_decode
GPU rasterization is whitelisted on N4, N5, N7 and Moto X: 362779
Disabled Features: gpu_rasterization
Additional GPU rasterization whitelist for field trial: 380694
Disabled Features: gpu_rasterization_field_trial
EXT_occlusion_query appears to be buggy with Intel GPUs on Linux
Applied Workarounds: disable_ext_occlusion_query
Clear uniforms before first program use on all platforms: 124764, 349137
Applied Workarounds: clear_uniforms_before_first_program_use
Mesa drivers in Linux handle varyings without static use incorrectly: 333885
Applied Workarounds: count_all_in_varyings_packing
Disable partial swaps on linux drivers: 339493
Applied Workarounds: disable_post_sub_buffers_for_onscreen_surfaces

Version Information
Data exported   11/8/2014 3:51:21 AM
Chrome version  Chrome/37.0.2062.120
Operating system    Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
Software rendering list version 8.8
Driver bug list version 7.2
ANGLE commit id unknown hash
2D graphics backend Skia
Command Line Args   --enable-pinch --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end

Driver Information
Initialization time 621
Sandboxed   true
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x2a02
Optimus false
AMD switchable  false
Driver vendor   Mesa
Driver version  10.1.3
Driver date 
Pixel shader version    1.20
Vertex shader version   1.20
Machine model name
Machine model version
GL_VENDOR   Intel Open Source Technology Center
GL_RENDERER Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2
GL_VERSION  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

GL_EXTENSIONS   GL_ARB_multisample GL_EXT_abgr GL_EXT_bgra GL_EXT_blend_color GL_EXT_blend_minmax GL_EXT_blend_subtract GL_EXT_copy_texture GL_EXT_polygon_offset GL_EXT_subtexture GL_EXT_texture_object GL_EXT_vertex_array GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array GL_EXT_texture GL_EXT_texture3D GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip GL_ARB_point_parameters GL_EXT_draw_range_elements GL_EXT_packed_pixels GL_EXT_point_parameters GL_EXT_rescale_normal GL_EXT_separate_specular_color GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp GL_SGIS_texture_lod GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GL_ARB_multitexture GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 GL_ARB_texture_cube_map GL_ARB_texture_env_add GL_ARB_transpose_matrix GL_EXT_blend_func_separate GL_EXT_fog_coord GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_EXT_secondary_color GL_EXT_texture_env_add GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias GL_INGR_blend_func_separate GL_NV_blend_square GL_NV_light_max_exponent GL_NV_texgen_reflection GL_NV_texture_env_combine4 GL_S3_s3tc GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp GL_ARB_texture_compression GL_EXT_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc GL_EXT_texture_env_combine GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3 GL_MESA_window_pos GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil GL_NV_texture_rectangle GL_ARB_depth_texture GL_ARB_occlusion_query GL_ARB_shadow GL_ARB_texture_env_combine GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_ARB_window_pos GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap GL_EXT_stencil_two_side GL_EXT_texture_cube_map GL_NV_depth_clamp GL_APPLE_packed_pixels GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object GL_ARB_draw_buffers GL_ARB_fragment_program GL_ARB_fragment_shader GL_ARB_shader_objects GL_ARB_vertex_program GL_ARB_vertex_shader GL_ATI_draw_buffers GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3 GL_ATI_texture_float GL_EXT_shadow_funcs GL_EXT_stencil_wrap GL_MESA_pack_invert GL_NV_primitive_restart GL_ARB_depth_clamp GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow GL_ARB_half_float_pixel GL_ARB_occlusion_query2 GL_ARB_point_sprite GL_ARB_shading_language_100 GL_ARB_sync GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_read_format GL_ARB_color_buffer_float GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc GL_ARB_texture_float GL_ARB_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_packed_float GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1 GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc GL_EXT_texture_rectangle GL_EXT_texture_sRGB GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent GL_ARB_framebuffer_object GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil GL_APPLE_object_purgeable GL_ARB_vertex_array_object GL_ATI_separate_stencil GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 GL_EXT_draw_instanced GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters GL_EXT_texture_array GL_EXT_texture_integer GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_EGL_image GL_ARB_copy_buffer GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float GL_ARB_draw_instanced GL_ARB_half_float_vertex GL_ARB_instanced_arrays GL_ARB_map_buffer_range GL_ARB_texture_rg GL_ARB_texture_swizzle GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects GL_EXT_texture_swizzle GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra GL_NV_conditional_render GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility GL_ARB_debug_output GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions GL_ARB_provoking_vertex GL_ARB_sampler_objects GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev GL_EXT_provoking_vertex GL_EXT_texture_snorm GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba GL_ARB_get_program_binary GL_ARB_robustness GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt3 GL_ANGLE_texture_compression_dxt5 GL_ARB_internalformat_query GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment GL_ARB_texture_storage GL_AMD_shader_trinary_minmax GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding GL_KHR_debug GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge
Window system binding vendor    SGI
Window system binding version   1.4
Window system binding extensions    GLX_ARB_create_context GLX_ARB_create_context_profile GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float GLX_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_ARB_multisample GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB GLX_EXT_import_context GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap GLX_EXT_visual_info GLX_EXT_visual_rating GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer GLX_OML_swap_method GLX_SGI_swap_control GLX_SGIS_multisample GLX_SGIX_fbconfig GLX_SGIX_pbuffer GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group GLX_INTEL_swap_event
Direct rendering    Yes
Reset notification strategy 0x8261

Log Messages
[3890:3890:1108/025315:ERROR:sync_control_vsync_provider.cc(60)] : glXGetSyncValuesOML should not return TRUE with a media stream counter of 0.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to disable hardware acceleration using `--disable-gpu`.

I have the same problem with Chromium version 41.0.2272.76 on Ubuntu 14.04
and  Intel Open Source Technology Center

```
GL_RENDERER Mesa DRI Intel(R) 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2
GL_VERSION  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
GPU0    VENDOR = 0x8086, DEVICE= 0x2a02
```

The screen goes black, but the system still works fine. I could  even switch to virtual terminal 3 (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), type user and password (with no visual feedback of course) and shutdown pressing the power button. My laptop really turned off. So its clear the system is running fine.

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1525. There is a [bug report for this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=443424).